# Jquery load method to upload multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

I have to upload A & B html page in C(parent) html page. I am using jQuery load method. A & B page also contain external javascript([requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)) file.

**Question:**

**1.** Load method will be best way to do or is there any other good way?

**2.** A & B html page is not loading in C page, is due to they contain JS file??

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test1").load("t1.html");
$("#test2").load("t2.html");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are `t1.html` , `t2.html` document fragments , or full `html` document ? See http://api.jquery.com/load#script-execution

Comment: Full html which also have external JS

Comment: Try reducing `html` to document fragments which do not have `<!DOCTYPE html` declaration . Is any `html` loaded into document ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this way.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```